# Fundamental groups of open sets in $R^n$ with $n=3,4$

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, 3-manifolds, fundamental-group, 4-manifolds

It is well known that every finitely presented group may be realised as fundamental group of some closed $4$-manifold.

> What groups can be obtained as fundamental groups of open subsets of $R^4$? I'm also interested in the same question with $n=3$

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be open even for $\mathbb{R}^3,$ see [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/4478/torsion-in-homology-or-fundamental-group-of-subsets-of-euclidean-3-space) and many enlightening answers thereto. See also the very nice answer to [this MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1362655/fundamental-group-of-open-subsets-of-mathbbrn), which gives some obstructions in $\mathbb{R}^3.$